# ExpressJS route regex: how to match a param to everything except one route

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I have a route defined something like this to catch `code` param:

```
app.get('/:code([a-zA-Z]{3})', codeHandler);
```

It matches all codes which are three letter long, and it is working fine. But I want to change  it to match every code except one. For example, lets say I want to exclude "cct". I tried using negative lookahead to excude "cct" from route by
modifying the above matcher like so:

```
app.get('/:code((?!cct)[a-zA-Z]{3})', codeHandler);
```

But now this route doesnt match anything. Even valid codes that used to be caught earlier are now not matching. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest way to do this would be to leave your regex as it is, but inside the codeHandler function have something along the lines of:

```
if(req.url == '/cct') return next();
```

Then express will move on to the next route handler.  If you've defined one for '/cct' it will go to that one - if not it will cause a 404 error because the page isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
app.get(/^\/((?!cct)[a-zA-Z]{3})$/, (req,res) => {

   console.log(req.params[0]);

})
```

Comment: one benefit I get from original route was it triggered my `app.param` handler which processed param `:code`, looked up data from DB and assigned that to `req` object. Is there a way to still trigger registered `param` handler.